How do I maintain connection between Docker containers while having one of them connected to host machine?
I am currently deploying an application with Docker (version 27.2.1), using docker compose on debian 11.
My docker-compose.yml file consists in defining 4 containers (app, api, db and ngninx).
app and api are Django applications. db is a postgresql service.
The whole is deployed on a machine that hosts an SMTP service on port 25.
My Django app app needs to use this service to send emails to the users, but it also has to be able to connect with the other containers. For example, db is the host of the postgresql server that contains all the data managed by the Django models defined in app.
I cannot find how my containers can be on the same network while having the app service in relation to the host machine. This prevents me from using the SMTP I need to use. From what I have read on this site and in the docs, it seems that it is not possible to have a service running on both network_mode=host and on a default bridge network.
Here is the docker-compose.yml file.
services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      ...
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
      
  api:
    build: ./api
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy    
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
      ...

  db:
    build: ./db
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U user-h localhost -d database"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      ...
    depends_on:
      - app
      - api

volumes:
  ...

Once I get how to connect to the host machine successfully, I will modify my settings.py for the correct EMAIL_HOST.
I have tried several options.
First, I added this mention in the app part of the docker-compose file:
extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

But, when I get into the app container and try, for example, telnet host.docker.internal 25, the connection is refused.
I tried to directly bind the port of the host machine to a port of the app container. When using this configuration and executing telnet <ip_address_of_host> 25, the connection succeeds but is immediately closed by the foreign host.
The other options I have tried so far are not viable as they were using simultaneously host mode and networks.

If you're on a native-Linux host, the extra_hosts: setting you have should make host.docker.internal work (if you're using Docker Desktop, the host name should work without that).  But, if the host's SMTP daemon is only listening on 127.0.0.1, it might not be reachable from a container this way (the request will look like it comes from a Docker bridge interface and not "from localhost") and you'd have to reconfigure it.
